# Ubuntu 20.04 - iptables don't reload on startup

Tags: iptables

I have a script which loads iptables at `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptablesload`:

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules

ip6tables-restore < /etc/ip6tables.rules

exit 0
```

I also have a script which save iptables at `/etc/network/if-post-down.d/iptablessave`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# By saving the current iptables rules to the file at the specific path, 
# then they will be loaded on every startup.

echo "Saving current iptables rules..."

iptables-save -c > /etc/iptables.rules
if [ -f /etc/iptables.downrules ]; then
   iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.downrules
fi

ip6tables-save -c > /etc/ip6tables.rules
if [ -f /etc/ip6tables.downrules ]; then
   ip6tables-restore < /etc/ip6tables.downrules
fi


exit 0
```

I have a file at path `/etc/iptables.rules` which contains all the rules.

When I manually execute `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules` then I can see all iptables rules.
But after powering on the PC, then all iptables rules are missing (all is empty).

My conclusion is that the scripts in folders `/etc/network/if-post-down.d` and `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d` don't execute. Why?

(The file `/etc/iptables.rules` exists because I manually executed `iptables-save -c > /etc/iptables.rules`.)

---

I'm using the exact same scripts that I used for Ubuntu 18 - they worked well.

The above is originally taken from:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Solution_.232_.2Fetc.2Fnetwork.2Fif-pre-up.d_and_...2Fif-post-down.d

I also tried copying exactly as they write in [the link above](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Solution_.232_.2Fetc.2Fnetwork.2Fif-pre-up.d_and_...2Fif-post-down.d), but still iptables failed to load.

Comment: Correct, they don't execute because the `/etc/interfaces` file and ifupdown are not used anymore. Ubuntu has switched to networkd, which is just a front end for systemd-networkd. I used to do your method also, and still do on my 16.04 server. I do not like netplan and am doing it now directly with networkd as a post-boot process on my newer server.

Comment: Please clarify your release(s).  Ubuntu uses *yy* releases only for specialist *snap* based releases for IoT appliances/devices or cloud based use (having done so since 2016). Main releases use *yy.mm* such as used by server & desktops releases.

Comment: @guiverc: Release is 20.04

Comment: Please correct your question, Ubuntu Core 20 and releases using the *yy* format are different products to *yy.mm* releases, having been so since 2016

Comment: I would suggest relying on the `iptables-persistent` package instead of relying on your own scripts.  The package i just specified also adapts for NetworkD by loading up the scripts as a SystemD rule/task instead of linking into `ifupdown`

Answer (score 1):

**Update– networkd**

The OOTB configuration in Ubuntu now uses the `iptables-persistent` package. As pointed out, this is the solution for recent releases:

```
sudo apt install iptables-persistent
netfilter-persistent save
netfilter-persistent reload
```

This will persist iptables rules between sessions.

**Original Answer**

It appears that the file you are looking for is now called
`/etc/iptables/rules.v4`

e.g.

```
sudo cat /etc/iptables/rules.v4
# position 1
*filter
# [snip] -- I checked the rules, they are there
```

So you should be able to

```
# must be root
sudo -i 
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

and to restore:

```
# must be root
sudo -i
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
ip6tables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

Comment: The scripts in use by OP won't work anymore because networkd is used not ifupdown